# SwiftUI unintentional Root View navigation from sheetView

Tags: swiftui, view, navigationview

I'm having an issue with navigation view and using a popup view to add a core data object. When I dismiss the view instead of going one view back it goes to the root view. This is frustrating especially when you are 5 views in and just want to go back one view.

I've tried many ways to dismiss the view. I have tried different ways of calling and dismissing the popup view including:

Dismissing view:

`@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationModel`

then

`self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`

Calling and Dismissing view:

`@State var showAddObjectView = false`

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
            self.showAddObjectView.toggle()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "plus").imageScale(.large).font(Font.system(.body)).padding(15).accentColor(Color("BlackWhite"))
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showAddObjectView) {
            AddMoodView(showAddMood: $showAddMood, person: person).environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.managedObjectContext)
        })
```

Then in the sheet view:

`@Binding var showAddObjectView: Bool`

Then on the save button:

`self.showAddMood = false`

Comment: It’s actually a bug in SwiftUI.

Comment: Try moving `sheet` out of the `navigationBarItems` and place it directly in the `body`.

Comment: Good to know that it is a bug. I will try moving the sheet out of navigationBarItems. Will let you know the results.

Comment: That works much better(now not going directly to root view) but now as soon as I go to the detail view it holds for about 1 second then goes to the root view. The sheet view is a navigation view is that the issue? The root view goes to the detail view with NavigationLink.

Comment: So after much experimentation moving the `sheet` out of the `navigationBarItems` works but it intermittently works. Submitted the bug to Apple. Thanks for your help!